# Table View Cell Segues not Working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to do something very simple: set up a segue so that when you click on a cell in a table it will take you to another View Controller. The problem, I believe, originates from the fact that the TableView these cells are in is embedded in a regular ViewController (as opposed to a TableViewController), and is one of two subviews in this ViewController.

As far as I can tell, I've set everything up correctly: I embedded the ViewController with the two subviews in a Navigation Contoller, set it to be the dataSource and delegate for the TableView, and created a push segue from a TableViewCell to my second View Controller in the storyboard.  However, when the app is run and a user clicks a row in the table, it merely selects the row and the segue doesn't fire at all (I've debugged it and the prepareForSegue function isn't even being called).

Is there something I'm missing here?  Or is this for some reason not possible if the TableView is not the only view in its view controller?

Comment: Have you given the table cells unique identifiers?

Comment: I give the cells the identifier "LoadCell" both in the storyboard (in the attributes of the prototype cell) and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function; is this correct, or should each individual cell be given a distinct identifier when it is created?

Answer (score 6):

I find that if I had recently wired the segue from the cell's accessory view, and later delete the segue and try to wire a new segue to the cell directly it does *not* work (using Xcode 4.6.2) -- Xcode keeps connecting the segue to the accessory view (even if there isn't one)! The way I fixed it is by selecting the cell in IB and using the connection inspector to (1) delete the original "accessory action" segue and (2) directly wire the "selection" segue by dragging from the filled circle in the image below to the appropriate destination view controller.

[image]

Comment: still relevant for Xcode 8 :)
thanks a lot. solved my issue

Comment: This is still an issue for me in Xcode 13.

Answer (score 4):

This may or may not help you, but I ran into this issue because I had defined two different cell types, and had provided `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` implementation. I had to add `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Whatever" sender:self]` as part of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the issue got resolved.

If you are able to at least detect row selections, you may be able to take advantage of this method.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, but with the the sender as the cell: `sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

Answer (score 4):

If you have customized the cell rendering, e.g.:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

then ensure you are using the same cell identifier as specified for the prototype cell in ste story.

So in this case the 'Identifier' of the cell which hooked up the segue should be set to '**Cell**'.

Comment: Spent the past two hours trying to figure this out (only just started messing around with Objective-C this evening. Thanks a lot, that was driving me mad!

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the StoryBoard in Xcode then do the following:

1. Create a UITableViewController
2. Add a prototype UITableViewCell
3. Create the UIViewController that will be your segue target.
4. Control-Click on the prototype UITableViewCell and drag to the segue target.

That's it.  You'll probably want to edit the characteristics of the UITableViewCell to be, for example, your subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: This is precisely what I have done, except that instead of having a UITableViewController I have a regular UIViewController, with a UITableView (as well as another UIView) as subviews within the main view.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: In Xcode, is the tableViewCell 'push' storyboard segue linked to the controller that is your segue target?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue.
Fix is 
1. Write SegueIdentifier for the segue in Storyboard
2. Add the following line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:nil];  in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

I hope this would help.

Comment: Adding performSegueWithIdentifier makes my app crash, throwing an Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCell _setHostsLayoutEngine:]. Apparently nobody has had/solved this issue before as there's no answer for it here on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Segue from a prototype table view cell inside a regular View Controller would make the app crash. In case someone have the same problem.

My solution:

If you are using a push segue make sure your first View Controller with the table view is embedded in a Navigation Controller otherwise "push segues" wont work. Also point the segue at the destination View Controller, not its Navigation Controller!

And as mentioned earlier, make sure your "segue identifiers" are correct.

at "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" I call "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your_destination_View_Controller" sender:self];

Comment: Adding performSegueWithIdentifier makes my app crash, throwing an Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCell _setHostsLayoutEngine:]. Apparently nobody has had/solved this issue before as there's no answer for it here on SO.